# Could you please tell me what “whipped fish” means in the following text (from Hemingway’s newly discovered short story "Pursuit as Happiness")?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There was no question anymore of catching the fish as a world’s record or any other sort of record, since the rod was broken. But he was a **whipped fish** now and on the heavy gear we should get him. The only problem was that the big rod was too stiff for the fifteen-thread line. That was my problem and I would have to work it out.

Comment: Whipped here means exhausted, tired, beaten.

Comment: Oh, thank you :)